# TestFixtureSetup skipped when debugging tests

Tags: vb.net, nunit, visual-studio-debugging

If I try to debug the following code using the *Test With -> Debugger* option from within VS2010, it falls over on `_object.DoSomething()` with an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error. It builds and passes successfully in NUnit.

```
<TestFixture()>
Public Class Tests

    Private _object As SomeClass

    <TestFixtureSetUp()>
    Public Sub TestFixtureSetup()
        _object = New SomeClass()
    End Sub

    <Test()>
    Public Sub Test()
        _object.DoSomething()
    End Sub

End Class
```

It seems that `<TestFixtureSetUp()>` is being skipped when I debug. To workaround, I have amended `Test` -

```
<Test()>
Public Sub Test()
    If Debugger.IsAttached Then
        TestFixtureSetup()
    End If          
   _object.DoSomething()
End Sub
```

But should I need to do this or is this skipping of `TestFixtureSetup` when debugging by design.

Comment: Have you tried just <SetUp> intead off TestFixtureSetup

Comment: Still the same behaviour. It appears to me that when debugging tests, the usual "test" events are not fired. For example, if I set a breakpoint in the

Comment: When using the "Test With -> Debugger" option only the test method under the cursor is debugged and the expected sequence of NUnit "test" events are not fired. For example, if I set a breakpoint in <TestFixtureSetup> and also in the <Test>, then fire off debugging against <Test>, the breakpoint in <TestFixtureSetup> is not activated. And vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

May be a naming convention

Try:

```
<TestFixtureSetUp()>
Public Sub SetUp()
    _object = New SomeClass()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the same behaviour.